# What is the most efficient computation of the permanent?

Tags: computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

There are a number of way to compute the permanent, and I'm wondering between the Ryser's formula, the Balasubramanian-Bax-Franklin, and the Glynn formula, whether there is a noticeable difference in computational speed. On Wikipedia, it says that the latter two formulas are just as fast as Ryser's, but then says that they may in fact be twice as fast. Is there a way to mathematically prove that one or the others are superior in efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

Glynn's formula has a time-complexity of $$O(n2^n)$$ whereas, Ryser's formula has a time-complexity of $$O(n^22^n)$$
So, Glynn's formula is the most efficient general purpose algorithm for computing the permanent. However, some special cases have faster algorithms as briefly explained in the source below.

Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.01260.pdf